# Compare dates in drools

Tags: java, jboss, drools, drools-guvnor, drools-fusion

My rule file as below,

```
import com.springapp.mvc.model.Person; 
dialect "java"
rule "4" 
    when
        $person:Person(((date > "20-Jan-2015") && (date < "20-Dec-2015")) && (call_count >= "299"))
    then
        System.out.println("Beep");
end
```

I added following person object and fire rules as below,

```
Person person = new Person();
person.date = "20-Feb-2015";
person.call_count = 400;
kSession.insert(person);
int fires = kSession.fireAllRules();
```

But it didn't print "Beep". I think conditions are not matched but I can't understand why this happen. How can I compare dates in drools?

My actual rule set,

```
package Customer_Loyalty_Categorization;
import com.springapp.mvc.model.Person; 
dialect "java"

rule "4" 
    when
        $person:Person(((date > "10-Nov-2015") && (date < "10-Dec-2015")) && (call_count >= "299"))
        $person:Person(((date > "10-Nov-2015")&&(date < "30-Dec-2015")) && (call_count >= "299"))
    then
        System.out.println("Point rule runs.");
        $person.points = ($person.call_count)*0.2;
end

rule "6" 
    when
        $person:Person(call_count >= "599")
    then
        System.out.println("Category rule runs.");
        $person.setCategory('PLATINUM');
end
```

And after changing type of the date variable of the person I got following exception,

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to Analyse Expression date > "20-Nov-2015":
[Error: Comparison operation requires compatible types. Found class java.util.Date and class java.lang.String]
[Near : {... date > "20-Nov-2015" ....}]
                    ^
[Line: 8, Column: 8] : [Rule name='4']

Unable to Analyse Expression date < "20-Dec-2015":
[Error: Comparison operation requires compatible types. Found class java.util.Date and class java.lang.String]
[Near : {... date < "20-Dec-2015" ....}]
                    ^
[Line: 8, Column: 8] : [Rule name='4']

Unable to Analyse Expression date > "01-Jan-2015":
[Error: Comparison operation requires compatible types. Found class java.util.Date and class java.lang.String]
[Near : {... date > "01-Jan-2015" ....}]
                    ^
[Line: 40, Column: 8] : [Rule name='1']

Unable to Analyse Expression date < "07-Jan-2015":
[Error: Comparison operation requires compatible types. Found class java.util.Date and class java.lang.String]
[Near : {... date < "07-Jan-2015" ....}]
                    ^
[Line: 40, Column: 8] : [Rule name='1']

Unable to Analyse Expression date > "01-Jan-2015":
[Error: Comparison operation requires compatible types. Found class java.util.Date and class java.lang.String]
[Near : {... date > "01-Jan-2015" ....}]
                    ^
[Line: 48, Column: 8] : [Rule name='2']

Unable to Analyse Expression date < "07-Jan-2015":
[Error: Comparison operation requires compatible types. Found class java.util.Date and class java.lang.String]
[Near : {... date < "07-Jan-2015" ....}]
                    ^
[Line: 48, Column: 8] : [Rule name='2']

Unable to Analyse Expression date > "05-Jan-2015":
[Error: Comparison operation requires compatible types. Found class java.util.Date and class java.lang.String]
[Near : {... date > "05-Jan-2015" ....}]
                    ^
[Line: 48, Column: 8] : [Rule name='2']

Unable to Analyse Expression date < "10-Jan-2015":
[Error: Comparison operation requires compatible types. Found class java.util.Date and class java.lang.String]
[Near : {... date < "10-Jan-2015" ....}]
                    ^
[Line: 48, Column: 8] : [Rule name='2']
```

I'm generating rules as set of strings and convert them into knowledgebase using following function,

```
public void createKnowledgeBase(){
        String ruleSet = loadRuleSet();//generate rules as strings.
        try {
            System.out.println(ruleSet);
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if(ruleSet!=null){
                KnowledgeBuilder knowledgeBuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
                Resource myResource = ResourceFactory.newReaderResource(new StringReader(ruleSet));
                knowledgeBuilder.add(myResource, ResourceType.DRL);
                if (knowledgeBuilder.hasErrors()) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(knowledgeBuilder.getErrors().toString());
                }
                knowledgeBase = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase();
                knowledgeBase.addKnowledgePackages(knowledgeBuilder.getKnowledgePackages());
            }
            long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("Execution time = " + (finish-start) + " milliseconds.");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm using Drools 6.3.0. If I remove date comparison part this rule works fine.

Comment: Aah, finally - the missing information has arrived. See yet another addition to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you have

```
class Person {
    String date;
    // ...
}
```

So that

```
when
    $person:Person(((date > "20-Jan-2015") ...
```

results in a string (!) comparison of

```
"20-Feb-2015" > "20-Jan-2015" && "20-Feb-2015" < "20-Dec-2015"
```

which may even work at times, but mostly it wont. You should use

```
class Person {
    java.util.Date date;
    // ...
}
```

You need to change

```
person.date = new Date( 115, 1, 20 ); // or, preferably, parse a string
```

but you can leave the rule as it is; Drools will convert a string to a Date value (provided it corresponds to your locale setting).

**Later** After some experiments, I find that 6.3.0 (and probably earlier versions) have a rather weird behaviour when compiling comparisons of java.util.Date to String.

```
rule x1 when
  Person(date > "10-Jan-2000")              // OK
  Person($date:date, date > "10-Jan-2000")  // OK
  Person($date:date, $date > "10-Jan-2000") // Error (types incompatible)
```

It is absolutely confusing when a programmer may not rely on the fact that a bound variable behaves like the property to which it is bound.

**Finally:**
**Don't use public fields in your fact classes. Stay with the Java Beans model and declare getters and setters.** It turns out that Drools isn't using the automatic conversion from String to java.util.Date when a (public) instance variable itself is accessed due to the lack of a getter.

Comment: then should I have to convert  "20-Dec-2015" into date value using date format (eg: DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);).

Comment: You only need to change the assignment to `person.date`. Drools takes care of converting the String containing a date in the condition. - See the addition to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your support laune. But this gives me an exception. (Comparison operation requires compatible types. Found class java.util.Date and class java.lang.String)

Comment: Well. it works for me, using 6.2.0. Please add the stackdump to your question.

Comment: it gives this exception. 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to Analyse Expression date > "20-Nov-2015":
[Error: Comparison operation requires compatible types. Found class java.util.Date and class java.lang.String]
[Near : {... date > "20-Nov-2015" ....}]

Comment: Hashita, you didn't post the exact rule where the problem occurs. - See my addition to the answer.

Comment: My exact rule is also as in original post difference is it has this line. $person.points = ($person.call_count)*0.2; in the "then" clause of the rule.

Comment: I just added my actual rule set and the exception to the original post.

Comment: So this should be it - I can see clearly now that you are accessing instance variables (date, points, call_count) directly. Make sure to use getters and setters.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [`org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html#parseDate(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])). I got same kind of problem and this one worked for me, may be will work on yours.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils; 

$person: Person((date > DateUtils.parseDate("20-01-2015", "dd-MM-yyyy") && date < DateUtils.parseDate("20-12-2015", "dd-MM-yyyy")) && (call_count >= "299"));
```

Comment: before generating the rule condition I cannot figure out what is the variable type of the left and right side of the condition. Because I'm generating rules dynamically using a database.